# Error installing karma on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to install karma using

```
npm install -g karma
```

but, even as the admin, I'm getting these errors:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'Z:\\Users\\vazirin\\Downloads\\Node\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'Z:\\Users\\vazirin\\Downloads\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'karma' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.3
3 info using node@v0.10.11
4 verbose node symlink Z:\Users\vazirin\Downloads\Node\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'karma', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="karma" args=["karma",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'karma',
7 verbose parsed url   path: 'karma',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'karma' }
8 silly lockFile 512423cb-karma karma
9 verbose lock karma Z:\Users\vazirin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\512423cb-karma.lock
10 silly lockFile 512423cb-karma karma
11 silly lockFile 512423cb-karma karma
12 verbose addNamed [ 'karma', '' ]
13 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
14 silly lockFile cd7961bb-karma karma@
15 verbose lock karma@ Z:\Users\vazirin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cd7961bb-karma.lock
16 silly addNameRange { name: 'karma', range: '*', hasData: false }
17 verbose url raw karma
18 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './karma' ]
19 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
20 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 12:57:46
21 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be    established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
23 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 12:57:58
24 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
26 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 12:59:00
27 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
28 silly lockFile cd7961bb-karma karma@
29 silly lockFile cd7961bb-karma karma@
30 error Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
30 error     at ClientRequest.onError (Z:\Users\vazirin\Downloads\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:159:17)
30 error     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
30 error     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
30 error     at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1517:9)
30 error     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
30 error     at net.js:829:16
30 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
31 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
31 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
31 error or email it to:
31 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
32 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
33 error command "Z:\\Users\\vazirin\\Downloads\\Node\\\\node.exe" "Z:\\Users\\vazirin\\Downloads\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "karma"
34 error cwd Z:\Users\vazirin
35 error node -v v0.10.11
36 error npm -v 1.3.3
37 error code ECONNRESET
38 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I have no problem running this on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Googling the stuff where the error starts seems to point at some config issues possibly: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2677

Comment: I'm trying to see where the issue would be in config. Did some deletions, changed some proxies, and made sure the right registry is being accessed. Now I'm getting a different set of errors mostly related to fstream.

Comment: Sorry haven't tried this on Win 7 to give you any details, just saw this going un-answered figured I'd try to give you some direction, but I think getting Karma running on Windows sounds like a challenge.

Comment: Oh definitely. I'd instantly switch to Linux or BSD if I could. But for my purposes, I think I'll leave Karma alone and singly use Jasmine.

Comment: You could always VirtualBox too.

Comment: I've also thought about that but sadly that's not an option for me.

Comment: Are you behind proxy ?

Comment: I've checked for that. I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling node. Then used [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) to install it. That gave me a couple of errors but as I debugged, it turned out that for some reason, the npm config file had the wrong registry address to look up the packages. So when I executed

```
npm install -g karma
```

it would try to connect to the registry and couldn't. After fixing the address, everything worked smoothly. I was starting to question if my previously installed programs had changed any system config files or network settings. Evidently, there was no proxy issue encountered.